# Magento case price

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, inventory

I have two attributes for a product,first one is the unit price and second is the case price.
The unit price is the default price of the magento,for the case price i create a new attribute named case pirce.
My question is i display the prices in the product description,but it is not allowing me to add the case price to the shopping cart
Am i doing some thing wrong here,if so let me know the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using the new "Qty Increments" feature in conjunction with Tier Pricing.  If you look in the Inventory tab on the Product Edit screen, you can enable Qty Increments and set a value, which will enforce that the customer add products to the cart in batches equal to a multiple of the Qty Increment value.

Answer (score 1):

Products are added in quantities of 1, so a "case" isn't really a logical unit to the system. Some options:

- You could use javascript to add the product to the cart in the right quantity (for a case), but the user will be able to adjust this quantity.
- You could create a second, related product as "Case of X", but the inventory will not match up.
- You could create a product option for single/case quantities with a price, but this seems somewhat unintuitive and also has the quantity problem as above.*
- You could create a grouped product with a fixed quantity. This is a bit contrived, but makes the most sense from a bookkeeping perspective.

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joseph Mastey

Comment: it's not technically true that products must ONLY be added in quantities of 1, see my answer below.

Comment: Good point :) This may also suffer from usability issues, though.

Answer (score 1):

magento calls it "tier pricing" you should try and configure your "cases" by quantity and assign a discount for it